# Sheets API v4 OVERWRITE and INSERTROWS in AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, google-sheets-api

I am using Sheets API v4 in VB .NET

Following lines gives the same result:

```
Dim appendRequest As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Append(valueRange, updateSpreadsheetID, updateRange)
```

```
appendRequest.InsertDataOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.OVERWRITE
```

```
appendRequest.InsertDataOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.AppendRequest.InsertDataOptionEnum.INSERTROWS
```

But in the doumentation [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/values), it's mentioned that:

> "Additionally, you can choose if you want to overwrite existing data
>   after a table or insert new rows for the new data. By default, the
>   input overwrites data after the table. To write the new data into new
>   rows, specify insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS in the URL."

Instead of adding data to the last empty row of the range, I want to insert new data at the first row of the provided range.

Comment: The difference between these two commands is: if there is a table above another one in the same sheet with at least one blank row in between, the action of INSERT_ROWS vs OVERWRITE is different for the above table. OVERWRITE will write into the blank rows in between until the tables merge while INSERT_ROWS will hold the gap by inserting rows then writing into them.

Answer (score 1):

The values.append API does not support writing starting at the top of the table, it only supports adding rows to the bottom of the table (either by overwriting data that is below the table, or by inserting rows to write the new data into).

(But, if you want, you can use the [spreadsheets.batchUpdate API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) and manually construct requests to [insert new rows](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#InsertDimensionRequest) & [add data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest).)